# Merging a large string including httpURl

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I am trying to add some large string into string type varriable.But it gives an error.

```
 string SuccessUrl = "~/Customer/Success.aspx?URL=" + Server.UrlEncode("Transactionid="
                     + Transactionid + "&Amount=" + Amount + "&Name=" + Name +
                     "&EmailOfPayer=" + EmailOfPayer + "&bussness=" + business + "&CompanyName=" + CompanyName
                     + "&PaymentDate=" + paymentDateTime  +"&SecuritiesandComplianceFee=" + SecuritiesandComplianceFee
                     +"&Status=" + Convert.ToInt32(Status) + "&BackmyUri=" + BackmyUri);
```

I have an error because of the last varriable i.e. `BackmyUri`. The varriable have the string value as given below.

> string BackmyUri = "http://localhost:11181/Payment.aspx"

it gives an error .
**Input string was not in a correct format.**

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the value of the variable `Status`?

Comment: I'd already cheked it one by one problem is genrating when i am adding the varriable Backmyuri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Input string was not in a correct format.` is most likely the default error message for `int.Parse()` and `Convert.ToInt32' . You should really check that. Another helpful thing for us would be to show us an example that makes it error, show the result of:

```
var x = "Transactionid=" + Transactionid + "&Amount=" + Amount + "&Name=" + Name +
                         "&EmailOfPayer=" + EmailOfPayer + "&bussness=" + business + "&CompanyName=" + CompanyName
                         + "&PaymentDate=" + paymentDateTime  +"&SecuritiesandComplianceFee=" + SecuritiesandComplianceFee
                         +"&Status=" + Convert.ToInt32(Status) + "&BackmyUri=" + BackmyUri
```